# CSS not being applied using wp_enqueue_style

Tags: plugin-development, css, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to load my style sheets in my plugin but they are not being called, the javascript files however, are being loaded.

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: 
Plugin URI: 
Description: 
Version:
Author: 
Author URI: 
**/

define("MPF_PATH", ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/' );
define("MPF_URL", trailingslashit(get_option('siteurl')) . 'wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/' ); 


class mpf_plugin{

function crf_user_registration(){
    add_action('plugins_loaded', array(&$this, "load_my_scripts"));
    add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'add_crf_menu_items'));

    if(!is_admin()){
        add_shortcode('crf_registration', array(&$this, "do_shortcode"));
    } else {
        //do something else here

    }
}

function load_my_scripts(){
    if(is_admin()){
        wp_register_script('crf_script', MPF_URL . 'includes/js/crf_script.js');
        wp_register_style('crf_style', MPF_URL . 'includes/css/crf_style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('crf-style');

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('crf_script');

        wp_localize_script( 'crf_script', 'MyAjax', array( 'MPF_PATH' => MPF_PATH, 'MPF_URL' => MPF_URL,'ajaxurl' => MPF_URL . 'includes/save-layout.php', 'loadPageLayoutURL' => MPF_URL . 'includes/get-layout.php', 'optionsPageURL' => MPF_URL . 'includes/options.php' ));
    }
}


function do_shortcode(){

    include('crf_form.php');
}


function options_page() {
    // HTML code goes here, left out for brevity
}

function custom_dropdown_page(){
    // HTML code goes here, left out for brevity
}

function add_crf_menu_items() {
    add_menu_page(
            'My Plugin Form', 
            'MPF', 
            'manage_options', 
            'mpf-options', 
            array(&$this,'options_page')
        );

    add_submenu_page(
            'mpf-options', 
            'MPF Options', 
            'MPF Options', 
            'manage_options', 
            'custom-mpf-options', 
            array(&$this,'custom_dropdown_page')
        );
}

}

new mpf_plugin();
```

The paths are all correct.  Any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess it's because `plugins_loaded` is too early to enqueue styles. The `wp_enqueue_scripts` action is the appropriate action for enqueueing scripts and styles.

Comment: Thanks Milo.  What would you think is the right action to hook into?  And if plugins_loaded is too early then why does the javascript file load?

Comment: without looking into source, I'm not sure why the two would behave differently, but as I mention in my answer `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the action you should hook. see the example with [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style#Examples) in codex.

Comment: Thanks again Milo.  I had read your first response wrong.  Strange, but the style sheets still don't load with this hook.  I don't get it.

Comment: Did you see this example Todd? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style#Load_stylesheet_only_on_a_plugin.27s_options_page - looks like 'admin_init' is the action to use for registering.

Comment: @MereDevelopment yes, I have seen that and tried that as well but *still* to no avail.  It has to be something else that is going on as I have the scripts loading just fine using plugins_loaded and admin_init in my other plugins.  Thanks for chiming in Mere Dev.